# limit of a series equal to the value on boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_nx^n}$ be a real series which has nonnegative coefficients and converges for any $|x|<1$. Assume $f(x)$ is also bounded on $(-1,1)$. Can I conclude

$$\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}?$$

Comment: Hint: Show first that $f$ bounded implies $\sum a_n<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\sup_{x\in (-1,1)}|f(x)|<+\infty$, $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$, then for $x\in (0,1)$ and $n\geqslant 0$, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k\leqslant f(x)\leqslant M$, taking the limit as $x\rightarrow 1^-$ gives $S_n\leqslant M$. Thus $(S_n)$ is a bounded non decreasing sequence and therefore converges. Moreover,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^n (S_k-S_{k-1})x^k=\sum_{k=0}^nS_k x^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}S_k x^{k+1}=S_nx^n+(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^nS_k x^k $$
Taking the limit as $n\rightarrow +\infty$ gives $\displaystyle f(x)=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}S_k x^k$. Therefore, if $S=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}S_n$, we have
$$ S-f(x)=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(S-S_k)x^k $$
Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $p\geqslant 1$ such that $S-S_k\leqslant\varepsilon$ for $k\geqslant p$ and $\displaystyle\delta\leqslant\frac{\varepsilon}{\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(S-S_k)}$ then for $x\in (1-\delta,1)$, we have
$$ 0\leqslant S-f(x)\leqslant (1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(S-S_k)+\sum_{k=p}^{+\infty}(S-S_k)\leqslant 2\varepsilon $$
Which means that $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1^-}f(x)=S=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n$.